# Python DataFrame.to_csv causes characters with accents to load incorrectly in excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I have an issue where character with an accent such as the 'ë' in 'Citroën' are being read as 'CitroÃ«n' when I open the files in excel.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

I suspect the issue is to do with the encoding of the output file.

According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) the default encoding for the `to_csv` function is 'utf-8'. Try using 'utf-8-sig' instead, i.e.:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

That often does the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `utf-16`, it works for me, but if you have a problem with the separator option, do as it follows:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-16', sep='\t', index=False)
```